# Как исправить проблему с ЧПУ WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Появились дубли страниц в WordPress, между категориями товаров WooCommerce можно вставлять любые значения (222 в примере) и WordPress возвращает ответ 200 и страницу. А должны быть 404 редиректы.

Как можно сделать адекватную генерацию ЧПУ, без ручных редиректов и прописывания canonical?

Пример URL дублей:

```
https://siteurl.ru/product-category/222/sub-category/222/sub-sub-category/222/sub-sub-sub-category/

https://siteurl.ru/product-category/222/222/sub-category/222/222/sub-sub-category/222/222/sub-sub-sub-category/
```

Comment: Никому они там не должны быть, 404. Не надо слушать сеошные байки. Так работает WP, и это нужно для пагинации. И вообще, трогать там в структуре постоянных ссылок ничего не надо: https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/woocommerce-kill-performance/

Comment: Я понимаю, что так работает WP. И это не относится к пагинации, так как там между категориями товаров можно любые символы записать и любое количество. И пагинацию он с конца url берет. Просто там WP генерирует ЧПУ и он смотрит на последнюю категорию в url и по ней выдает страницу, а то что между адресом сайта и категорией находится его не волнует.